# netcat sending extra "X" UDP packets

Tags: python, sockets, netcat

Stealing from [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication) I have set up a small Python script which listens on a port and prints out all of the UDP packets it receives:

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print "received message:", repr(data)
```

Now I am using `netcat` to send data to this script. Here is my command line.

```
echo -e "foo:1|c" | netcat -v -u localhost 5005
```

And here is the output from Python:

```
received message: 'X'
received message: 'X'
received message: 'X'
received message: 'X'
received message: 'X'
received message: 'foo:1|c\n'
```

These first four or so "X" lines arrive at roughly one-second intervals, then the final two lines arrive roughly simultaneously.

My question is this: where are these extra "X" packets coming from, and if the source is `netcat`, then how can I prevent `netcat` from emitting them? This is BSD's `netcat`, I believe.

Answer (score 11):

> This is BSD's netcat, I believe.

I had the same issue, and when I did `nc --version` I indeed saw:

> This is nc from the netcat-openbsd package. An alternative nc is available in the netcat-traditional package.

Conventional wisdom is that the BSD is the "better" version *(see [What are the differences between netcat-traditional and netcat-openbsd?](https://askubuntu.com/a/426320))*

But anyway, the BSD sources is where one would have to look to find the relevant code for where the "X" is actually coming from.  And you don't have to look too hard!

http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/nc/netcat.c?rev=1.177

The smoking gun is a function `udptest()`:

```
/*
 * udptest()
 * Do a few writes to see if the UDP port is there.
 * Fails once PF state table is full.
 */
int
udptest(int s)
{
    int i, ret;

    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        if (write(s, "X", 1) == 1)
            ret = 1;
        else
            ret = -1;
    }
    return (ret);
}
```

And the conditions under which this is called is if `vflag` (Verbosity) or `zflag` (Port Scan Flag) are set:

```
if (vflag || zflag) {
    /* For UDP, make sure we are connected. */
    if (uflag) {
        if (udptest(s) == -1) {
            ret = 1;
            continue;
        }
    }
    ...
```

Regarding the *rationale* for why the `-v` switch would start throwing random data at the UDP port, I'd guess the idea is that those who are using `-v` want every bit of information they can get.  So the tradeoff of getting an early and vocal error message about the connection is worth it to help someone in a debugging situation.

But even so, my opinion would be that instead of sending the cryptic `"X"` that sending something like `"NETCAT UDP PING DUE TO -V OPTION"` would be better.  :-/

Answer (score 2):

For reasons I cannot determine, those `X` packets are being sent by the `-v` option to `nc`.  Try this instead:

```
echo -e "foo:1|c" | netcat -u localhost 5005
```

Comment: The [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) just says that `-v` "give[s] more verbose output". Do you think this could be a defect in `netcat`?

Comment: "*For reasons that I cannot determine*" was my way of saying, "I don't know why." I don't know if this is a defect in netcat or a designed feature of netcat, or an implementation detail.

Comment: @Robᵩ The benefit of open source is that [one can know...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42241513/211160)

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo -n "foo:1|c" > /dev/udp/localhost/5005`

Comment: On what OS does `/dev/udp` exist?

Comment: Ah, I see that is a bash feature, not an OS feature. I didn't know about that.

Comment: I wrote a /dev/udp on QNX long ago.  I am pretty sure there was something like that on plan 9 although it worked differently from what I vaguely remember.